# Python Loop copy specific line identified by a character into a csv file or any text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all I want to begin with the actual code I’m trying to make it work:

```
for Num in range(200,307):

    with open(work_path+"\RESULTS\RES"+str(Num)+"_power_total.res","r") as f:
        a=0
        for line in f.readlines():
             liste = line.split( )
             if liste[0] == '1' :       
                F=float(liste[1])
                W=float(liste[2])
        a = a + 1
            list.append(F)
            list.append(W)          
list=list[::-1]          
np.savetxt('res.csv', (list), delimiter=' ')
```

What I'm trying to do is :
Inside the "Results" folder there's a big amount of files that share the name except a number, thus the str(Num).

Note: Those ".res" files are just text files like it can be opened in Wordpad for example.

Anyway the .res files also have the same structure like 35 lines that all starts with the character : "#". Except at one line it starts with the number "1". After this number there's two numbers.
For example:

---

"# gibberish

"# gibberish

"# gibberish

"1    2.0E+5  5.051511E+10

"# gibberish

---

So what I'm trying to do is to simply scan all the files, read them and copy/paste all of the lines that starts with the number "1", into another file (the res.csv files) to be later used in Excel.

At the end I would like a res.csv file that look like this :

---

2.0E+5  5.051511E+10

2.5E+5  4.464868E+09

2.7E+5  5.1261461+09

etc...

---

Now for the errors I get, I keep having this : "IndentationError: unexpected indent"
But I don't see anything wrong with the indentation I put?

Btw I'm kinda new at programming so please bear with me.
Thanks in advance and best regards.

Comment: Can you please correct the indentations in the code segment? So we know what happens when

Comment: Which indentations in the code segment should be corrected? Like I just copy/paste the code I used here.    I also now have a new error : IndexError: list index out of range. Which is strange since I don't think I'm asking too much files to read?

Comment: Just make sure the indentation is the same here as it is in your code. One problematic line for example is `a = a + 1`

Comment: I'm sorry then because I didn't get your question. Also yes my  `a=a+1` is indeed at the same indentation as the `a=0`

Comment: What about the 5-space indentation of the two lines below the for-statement ?

Comment: The line `list.append(liste[1])` shouldn't work since list is a type and not a variable(and also shouldn't be a variable)...

Comment: Also F, W, liste seem to be quite unused. Maybe those list statements should be indented.

Comment: @zwitsch F and W are both variable in where I put the [1]. Also below the for-statement it's also indented that way.

Comment: @StrangeSorcerer It indeed doesn't work! It returns "IndexError: list index out of range"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cleaning the indents and putting the appends into the loop, it seems to work. I made it a function as well:

```
def process_file(myfile):
    my_list = []                      # create a list to hold filtered data 
    with open(myfile,"r") as f:
        a=0
        for line in f.readlines():
            liste = line.split()      # this line had 5-space indent
            if liste:                 # eliminate empty lines    
                if liste[0] == '1' :  # this line had 5-space indent
                    F=float(liste[1]) # F and W can be omitted if not used elsewhere
                    W=float(liste[2])
                    my_list.append(F)
                    my_list.append(W)          
        a = a + 1
    my_list=my_list[::-1]             # is this list inversion intended?
    return my_list

# print(process_file("some_file.txt"))   ===> [50515110000.0, 200000.0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I cannot upvote because my account is new buy it did solved my issues! Also you are correct, the list inversion shouldn't be intended! Now I just have to put every loop back in place to make it work. Thanks again you guys rock!

Comment: You can not (yet) vote up, but if the answer is accepted, then see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers